# Add()ing timespan doesn't seem to add them

Tags: c#, timespan

I have a function that calculates the total working hours by adding `TtimeSpan`s. I tried to search through the web and found something `TimeSpan.Add()`.

Here is some sample of my code:

```
TimeSpan TotalWorkHours = new TimeSpan(0,0,0);
List<TimeSpan> Interval = new List<TimeSpan>();

Interval.Add(TimeSpan.Parse("04:20:07"));
Interval.Add(TimeSpan.Parse("03:59:49"));

//Having a looping to Add in the Interval and combine the total work hours

for(int i = 0; i < Interval.count; i++)
{
    if(i == 0)
       TotalWorkHours = Interval[i];       
    else
       //This section will always add in "00:00:00"
       TotalWorkHours.Add(Interval[i]);
}
```

However, the resulting timespan alwys is `00:00:00`. Where does it go wrong?

Comment: @MahmoudGamal could you try to edit somewhat more than adding a few `inline code` tags? :)

Comment: @CodeCaster OK, Sorry I missed it.

Comment: @Jon Fixed, sorry for that. the Value is actually assign from somewher e else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're calling `Add`, but not using the result at all. `Add` doesn't change the value - it returns a new value. You want:

```
TotalWorkHours = TotalWorkHours.Add(Interval[i]);
```

Or more idiomatically, IMO:

```
TotalWorkHours += Interval[i];
```

Or even more idiomatically, to my mind:

```
// Note the casing of the variable names to follow conventions,
// and the fact that "intervals" is plural because it contains
// more than one interval.   
List<TimeSpan> intervals = ...;
var totalWorkHours = TimeSpan.Zero;
foreach (var interval in intervals)
{
    totalWorkHours += interval;
}
```

Or even just use LINQ aggregation:

```
var totalWorkHours = intervals.Aggregate(TimeSpan.Zero, (x, y) => x + y);
```

Comment: thanks for your clue. By the ways. what you mention regarding List<TimeSpan> is already edit.

Answer (score 2):

`Timespan` is immutable. Any method that looks like it alters the state actually returns a new instance with the adjstment made. Just change your code to:

```
TotalWorkHours = TotalWorkHours.Add(Interval[i]);
```